# laravel different type of serving leads to html5 video player rewind problem (video.currentTime problem) in chrome and opera

Tags: php, laravel, server, html5-video

There are two different ways to serve larael projects:

1. php artisan serve
2. go to localhost/laravelproject/public

When I use "php artisan serve" method html5 video rewind does not work and js method video.currentTime also does not work and can't be set or something. (Mentioned functionality works only in mozzila no chrom no opera)

When I use "go to localhost/laravelproject/public" method both video rewind and currentTime method work perfectly fine.

Questions:

1. I am still on learning curve and haven't deployed any projects on live server, so is it true that when project is deployed to live server it is served via public folder not with "php artisan serve" command?
2. Should I, for some reason, use only "php artisan serve" while developing the project?